# Using a function within a class in python (to use self or not)

Tags: python, function, class, self

```
class Neuralnetwork(object):

     def __init__(self, data):    
         self.data = data

     def scan(self):
         print(self.data)

     def sigmoid(self, z):
         g = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-z))
         return (g)

     a1 = sigmoid(7)
     print a1
```

I'm not sure why it won't print the a1 variable with the sigmoid function. It keeps kicking off an error saying that it requires 2 inputs instead of 1. But I thought that by calling the function within the class, I didn'tneed to supply self to it again?

Edit: I have the last two statements in there because I'm still testing things out to make sure that everything is doing what it's supposed to within the class.

Comment: Because `sigmoid` is a function within the class definition. Why did you indent `a1 = ..` and `print a1` to be part of the class? Why not put `def sigmoid` **outside** of the class definition if it is not meant to be a method?

Comment: are you sure about the indentation of your two last line. Seems it should be out of the class.

Comment: If you were calling it from *inside* a class method, you would need to call it as `self.sigmoid(7)`.  If you wanted to call it from *outside*, then you would need to create an *instance* of `Neuralnetwork` to call `obj.sigmoid(7)` on.

Comment: You are right, you don't need self if you call from the class. But then, this call should occur from another method. You cannot have floating calls within a class as here.

Comment: I tried caling it as self.sigmoid(7), and that didn't work either.

Comment: if you call it INSIDE your class you have to put it in a method

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't just have a call to a method defined in my class as a part of my class?

Comment: see the two answers below, they should help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sigmoid` is a method of the `Neuralnetwork` class, so you need to create an instance of the `Neuralnetwork` class first, before you can utilize the `sigmoid` function, if you're calling it after the class definition:

```
class Neuralnetwork(object):
     def __init__(self, data):    
         self.data = data

     def scan(self):
         print(self.data)

     def sigmoid(self, z):
         g = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-z))
         return (g)

# replace data and z with appropriate values
nn = Neuralnetwork(data)
a1 = nn.sigmoid(z)
print a1
```

If you need to use it within the class, put the block within a method:

```
class Neuralnetwork(object):
     def __init__(self, data):    
         self.data = data

     def scan(self):
         print(self.data)

     def sigmoid(self, z):
         g = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-z))
         return (g)

     def print_sigmoid(self, z):
         a1 = self.sigmoid(z)
         print a1

# replace data and z with appropriate values
nn = Neuralnetwork(data)
nn.print_sigmoid(z)
```

I also recommend changing the class name to `NeuralNetwork`, as per the PEP 8 Style Guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You're welcome! @a1letterword Please accept/vote the answers if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I notice that your sigmoid method does not use self at all, that is, it does not depend on the instance. You may put it outside the class as a normal function. But if it is closely related to the class, you may prefer to enclose it as a static method, removing completely the self from the sigmoid def:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

import math

class NeuralNetwork(object):

    def __init__(self, data):    
        self.data = data

    def scan(self):
        print(self.data)

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(z):
        g = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-z))
        return (g)

a1 = NeuralNetwork('abc')
print(a1.sigmoid(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

with the two last line outside your class (without indentation) you can modify them with:

```
a1 = Neuralnetwork(data).sigmoid(7)
print(a1)
```

but you have to give data to your class